# Python3 function that adds elements from master list together

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

So if master list is:
master_list = [“tom”, “bob”]

The new list should be:
new_list = [‘tomtom”, “tombob”, “bobbob”, “bobtom”]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the desired strings:

```py
import itertools

master_list = ["tom", "bob"]
new_list = list(''.join(entry) for entry in itertools.product(master_list, repeat=2))

# Prints ['tomtom', 'tombob', 'bobtom', 'bobbob']
print(new_list)
```